# Cannot install .NET Core on Ubuntu Bionic Beaver

Tags: 18.04, sdk, dotnet

I'm currently trying to install .NET Core on Ubuntu 18.04 following [these](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu18-04/sdk-current) instructions. But I always get the following message:

```
me@mine-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-2.1.200
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-sdk-2.1.200 : Depends: dotnet-runtime-2.0.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've found some posts about this issue but no help. I hope to get some proper information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing `libicu55`, you need to install the other package dependencies that won't install on their own:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-deps-2.2
sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-2.2
sudo apt-get install aspnetcore-runtime-2.2
```

Then `sudo apt=get install dotnet-sdk-2.x`

Answer (score 6):

first add the sources:

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.asc.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list 
sudo mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
```

after that:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.200
```

**sudo apt-get update** is important

source: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linux/ubuntu18-04

Comment: Well, as mentioned in my question, I followed the instruction from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu18-04/sdk-current which is exactly the same as your answer. So this doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Register Microsoft key and feed**

Before installing .NET, you'll need to register the Microsoft key, register the product repository, and install required dependencies. This only needs to be done once per machine.

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.asc.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list 
sudo mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
```

**Install .NET SDK**

Update the products available for installation, then install the .NET SDK.

In your terminal, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

Source - https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/rhel/sdk-current

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working. Errors are the same.

Comment: Try running 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get upgrade'. Then try to run the commands that i posted.

Comment: Same issue. Still not working

Comment: I am also facing same issue :(

Answer (score -1):

You need to install libicu55:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libicu55
```

And then install net core:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

Comment: The addition of repositories from a different release (without proper priority rules) is asking for trouble. Also I don't see how `libicu55` affects the situation at hand. -1